# confluent avro converter retrieve schema from schema registry by ID or topicName+version

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I set up a kafka s3 sink connector cluster and it works for kafka topics that have the schema name pattern -value.

the worker task can successfully consume and deserialize messages from these topics and sink to s3 in parquet

However, not all topics in my environment are designed to have schema name set as -value. Some topics share common schema.

Other component depends on schemaId in message metadata to retrieve schema from schema registry to de-serialize. They all work perfectly ok for all topics.

So my questions are:

- Checking the source code I've found that kafka connector will
  deserialize based on schema and version. Why version matters here? If
  schemaId can uniquely identify a schema in schema registry
- It seems that converter rely on three naming strategies instead of
  unique schemaId: TopicNameStrategy RecordNameStrategy
  TopicRecordNameStrategy What's the reason for it? I can imagine it's
  for performance (e.g. topicNameStragegy) so that you don't have to
  connect to schema registry per record, but with schemaId, you can do
  the same by caching the schema locally
- What's a quick solution to make converter work in my current
  environment where none of the above three strategy seem to fit the
  use cases.

topic name pattern: *env.type.srcapp.data.version* e.g.
`testing.enterprise.appName.trade.v1`

```
schema subject name that works: `testing.enterprise.appName.trade.v1-value`    

**schema subject name that does not work**: `testing.trade.schema_version`
```

Great thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of the AvroConverter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Answer of the second question.

TopicNameStrategy forces that topic uses single static schema subject. It's {topic}-value or {topic}-key. It's the default only for backwards compatibility purposes before different strategies were available, not for performance.

```
@Override
public String subjectName(String topic, boolean isKey, ParsedSchema schema) {
    return isKey ? topic + "-key" : topic + "-value";
}
```

RecordNameStrategy means records in topic are 'self-described'. In other words, topic and schemas are mapped dynamically in 1:N way.

```
@Override
public String subjectName(String topic, boolean isKey, ParsedSchema schema) {
    if (schema == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return getRecordName(schema, isKey);
}

protected String getRecordName(ParsedSchema schema, boolean isKey) {
    String name = schema.name();
    if (name != null) {
        return name;
    }
    // ... not important
}
```

But RecordNameStrategy cannot be used by some confluent platform components. E.g. ksql.

I recommend confluent document: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#how-the-naming-strategies-work

If you have all schemas in local file, you don't need to connect to schema-registry at all.

For example)

```
try (Producer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties)) {
    var record = new GenericData.Record(schema) {{
        put("name", "red brief");
        put("price", 10000);
        put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
        }};
    var producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, record);
    producer.send(producerRecord);
}

public String readSchema(String schemaName) {
    File schemaFile = new File(SCHEMA_HOME + schemaName + ".avsc");
    try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(schemaFile)) {
        return new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

$SCHEMA_HOME/schemaName.avsc is schema file name.

Hope be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Youngrok Ko. The issue now is that we don't have <topic-name>-value created for topic.  I really don't see the benefit of doing so.  The avro converter extracts the schemaId from magic bytes in avro message. Up to this point of time, avro convert should be able to retrieve the schema from schema registry based on schemaId. However, it queries schema registry to get subject names associated to this schema Id and then check if <topic-name>-value subject name can be found.  This is totally not necessary.

Comment: schema is embedded in avro file only. If you consume from kafka, only schemaId is wired into the message not the entire schema.

Comment: What I don't understand most if why avro convert reverse look up subject name by schemaID from schema registry. This is totally un-necessary. I know this because we have messages created based on different versions of compatible schema. I created <topic-name>-value schema for one schema ID but I hit the same error when kafka connector processes another message under the same topic but with a different schemaId (two schemas referred by the two IDs are back-ward compatible).

Comment: I just don't fully understand the rational behind the scene to look up schema by subject name instead of by the already known schema Id. What's the benefit?

Comment: @JinMa "The issue now is that we don't have <topic-name>-value created for topic." / Schema generated by source connector automattically like database cdc connectors. If you do not use such auto generating tool, schema must be registered by manually.

Comment: @JinMa The benefit. You may found it in the confluent document I linked. Key of the '-value' strategy is using "single static" schema. Ksql system runs a query on the stream attached to topic. Query specifies columns (like select a, b, c ..) matched to avro schema. So ksql requires one static schema per topic.

Comment: @JinMa But as you say, if records are consumed by kafka-clients library, there's no differences between *Strateges. The <topic-name>-value is just naming rule and AvroDeserializer.class does not follows the rule. The deserializer retrieves the schema that is specified in record.

Comment: Theres's no way to customize <topic name>-value topic because its working is up to the s3 sink fully-managed connector. How about customizing strategy? My suggestion is defining your own strategy class by extending RecordNameStrategy. You can make own schema subject string of kafka record. Source code is quiet simple and you should override only subjectName method. TopicRecordNameStrategy class is an example of the extending.

Comment: I'm not sure what good the provided Java code provides since it is not possible to use that with Kafka Connect, as the question indicates without **more** code to write a custom Avro converter class that also doesn't use the Schema Registry

Comment: @OneCricketeer Good question. Those code snippets are parts of the strategy classes included in kafka-clients itself and Confluent inc already awares of that point. RecordNameStrategy is not also compatible with ksqldb as noticed in the confluent document. (linked in my answer)

Comment: `kafka-clients` doesn't have any "strategy classes". Those are all part of the schema registry serializer dependencies

Comment: @OneCricketeer Exact. Full path is io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy.